# ¿Como mantener los checkbox seleccionados en mi pagina web al refrescarla?

Tags: javascript, html

disculpen las molestias, estoy desarrollando un Filtro el cual manda los parámetros por medio de la URL, al seleccionar las opciones desde un checkbox de manera dinámica, mi problema es que al mandar el primer parámetro por la URL y recargar la vista con la información no se como mantener los checkbox seleccionado.

Ejemplo de mi URL

**miProyecto/tienda/color-blaco-negro**

En esta URL mando los parámetros **negro,blanco** ya que son los colores que filtrare dentro de un catalogo de porductos.

Este es el código con el que creo los checkbox para poder obtener esa información de la BD:

```
            <li> 
              <a class="active">Color</a> <span class="subDropdown plus"></span>
              <ul class="level0_415" style="display: none;">
                @foreach($colores as $color)
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="color[]" value="{{$color->color}}" id="filtros[]">
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">{{$color->color}}</label>
                <span class=""></span></li>
                @endforeach                 
              </ul> 
            </li>
```

Y de esta manera es como obtengo los parámetros y mando los mando por URL:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('[id="filtros[]"]').click(function(){

  var _url = window.location.href;

  var _color = $('[name="color[]"]:checked').map(function(){
    return this.value;
  }).get();
  var _str_color = _color.join('-');
  var col = _str_color.length;
  var _newcolor = "/" + "color-" + _str_color;
  });
});
</script>
```

Pero cuando me recarga la página no se como mantener los parámetros que tengo en la URL checkeados.

Saludos y agradezco por su ayuda y comentarios.

Comment: Hay varias forma de hacerlo, una de ellas es pasar por query params cuales están seleccionadas y marcarlas cuando se genera la página otra vez. Otra es  guardarlo en localstorage y hacer el mismo proceso

Comment: No se que es query params pero lo que te dice el compañero arriba, localStorage. Guardás ahi los valores queres que persistan al refrescar la página, y al cargar el sitio que primero busque esos valores en el localStorage, si no están que coloque unos por defecto.

Comment: Hola @nax de echo estaba revisando esta opción que me comentas con **window.localStorage** pero no supe bien como lo podía obtener de mi campo y como utilizarlo dentro de mi Script, me podrías explicar por favor, te lo agradecería mucho de antemano.Saludos

Comment: El localstorage solo lo podrás usar si estás creando los inputs desde cliente (javascript) si los estás usando desde PHP no podrás leer el local storage. Los query params son los parámetros en la url `example.com?queryPAram=valor`

Answer (score 2):

Como puedes utilizar jQuery te hago ver un ejemplo de como almacenar el estado de un checkbox en las cookies utilizando este [plugin](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie), donde está `#MiCheckbox` va el id de tu checkbox. Te invito a leer la documentación para ver como adaptarlo a tu proyecto:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@rc/dist/js.cookie.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $('#MiCheckbox').on('change', function(e){

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            //Guarda cookies por 7 días
            Cookies.set('mode', 'checkbox', { expires: 7 });
            
        } else {
            //Elimina cookies
            Cookies.remove('mode');
        }

    });
</script>
```